# How to removed xmlns:xsi and xsi:type from JAXB2Marshaller in java

Tags: java

I have a XML response like given below

```
<Movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="T_MOVIELIST0" totalMovies="2">
    <Movie>
        <DetailLevel0 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ExternalID>EN1skynetBSKY2014102807462817</ExternalID>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <DetailLevel0 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ExternalID>FR6skynetBSKY8607347700000000</ExternalID>
    </Movie>
</Movies>
```

and my JAXB2Marshaller  object factory is :

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TMOVIELIST }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "Movies0", scope = ResponseGetDetail.class)
public JAXBElement<TMovieList0> createResponseGetDetailMovies0(TMovieList0 value) {
    return new JAXBElement<TMovieList0>(_ResponseMovies_QNAME0, TMovieList0.class, ResponseGetDetail.class, value);
}
```

Because of these "xmlns:xsi and xsi:type" tags we are facing some performance issue.

Our requirement is response should be like below

```
<Response>

<Movies totalMovies="2">
    <Movie>
        <DetailLevel0/>
        <ExternalID>EN1skynetBSKY2014102807462817</ExternalID>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <DetailLevel0/>
        <ExternalID>FR6skynetBSKY8607347700000000</ExternalID>
    </Movie>
</Movies>

</Response>
```

Please let me know how we can do this..

Comment: you need to parse the xml and delete the attributes..

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["xsi:type" and "xmlns:xsi" in generated xml by JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679163/xsitype-and-xmlnsxsi-in-generated-xml-by-jaxb)